# Port forwarding isn't working on mac osx

Tags: osx, port-forwarding, telnet, nc

I've setup port-forwarding on my mac like this:

```
sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
echo "rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 445 -> 127.0.0.1 port 5441" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

To this setup, I am running a server using `nc` like this:

```
$ nc -l 5441
```

When I try to connect to this server via telnet, the attempt fails with the following error:

```
$ sudo telnet 127.0.0.1 445
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Running `tcpdump` on port `445` doesn't capture any packets. I am not sure what's going on and would appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `rdr` is only a redirect; one also may need a `pass` (or appropriate clicky around in the System Preferences) to permit access to that port. This works for me (though I've almost totally disabled the Apple firewall rules on my Mac OS X 10.11 laptop) in `/etc/pf.conf`:

```
set skip on { lo0, vboxnet0 }
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 445 -> 127.0.0.1 port 5441
block in
pass in inet proto tcp from any to any port 445
```

And then a `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` to load that and then testing with `nc -l 127.0.0.1 5441` and connections to port 445 from a remote machine shows access.

Hmm! However, *locally* to the Mac OS X system `telnet 127.0.0.1 445` fails, probably on account of the `skip lo0`. This can be rectified by not using `skip` if localhost access to the redirect is necessary:

```
set skip on vboxnet0
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 445 -> 127.0.0.1 port 5441
block in
pass on lo0
pass in inet proto tcp from any to any port 445
```

Also note that `locahost` may either mean `127.0.0.1` or `::1` so you may also need to setup `inet6` related rules, or ensure that the connections are always done with IPv4 so that IPv6 either works or is not used.

Comment: Thanks @thrig, this works. Few questions though. Do I need to disable all filtering on vboxnet0 (set skip on vboxnet0)? And why do I need to 'block in'?

Comment: `vboxnet0` is for virtualbox, which you may or may not have or may or may not need. `block in` blocks by default; not much of a firewall without that. I guess you could pass everything in... (also the Apple rules might complicate matter but again I've disabled those include)

Comment: Got it, May I complicate this a bit now? I am running nc based server on mac. I can telnet on port 445 from my mac, but I can't telnet on the same port from my windows 2012 virtual machine (virtualbox). Although, I can ping host mac from guest windows. Any idea why would that be?

Comment: Virtualbox will really depend on how you set up the networking and how virtualbox interacts with Apple's implementation of pf. That's why I have a `vboxnet0` that both the mac and any virts I want all live on, so they can communicate without the fuss of NAT.

Comment: What does "pass on lo0" mean here? And why do we specify a redirect rule before blocking in everything?

Comment: @user1071840 `pass on lo0` means pass traffic on the loopback interface, handy given the `block in` just above that. Last matching rule wins in PF. The redirect or translation happens before the packet filter rule because that's the order the `pf.conf(5)` manual specifies they should be in.